# Python how to get only the last 2 bytes of the reply data

Tags: jquery, python, python-2.7

I will post a query to a device which will return me with something like this (after a readlines):

```
['\x03C?01FF00\r']
```

I want to extract just the `FF00` and post the reply to the jquery (which sends the query) and display it out on browser. How can i do that? The 2 bytes range from 0000 to FFFF.

EDIT:
the reply type is `list`.

Comment: Unpack it with the `stuct` module.

Comment: do you mean `struct`? i can't find stuct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming `ans = ['\x03C?01FF00\r']`, `ans[0].strip()[-4:]` should yield 'FF00'

Comment: I have a question btw! what does -4: mean?

Comment: The -4: means to take a slice from the 4 characters back to the end (this was after the strip() took off the \n)